# runtime error in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm doing a problem on spoj to calculate no of bishops that can be placed on a board of n*n without attacking each other..

I decided to use java for it.. but my code is getting runtime error..pls help.

Code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;

class Bishop {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            int n = scanner.nextInt(); /*Error occurs here*/
            if (n == 1) {
                System.out.println("1");
                continue;
            }

            BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(n);

            BigInteger c = bi.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
            BigInteger d = c.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(2));

            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: what error, where...we can't read minds.

Comment: What error are you getting? I believe either your file does not exist or does not contain an integer.

Comment: @garyamorris he is reading from `System.in`

Comment: Dito. You might btw want to be carefull with importing * of a library as it's often considered bad style...

Comment: As above, we'd need the exact error message to be able to specifically help. It's also not good practice for your main method to throw an Exception - you're much better putting a try/catch block round portions of your code.

Comment: @karthik Tried it, working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

System.in is an InputStream, meaning it reads binary content. Unless you properly transform it to text beforehand, Scanner won't work correctly. In particular, if you don't provide Scanner with a CharSet, it will use your platform's default one, which may be different.

Alternatively, you may want to use the java.io.Console to read text from the standart input.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, this will just check that the scanner does indeed contain an integer.

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {

   int n =scanner.nextInt(); 
}
```